# Android source master branch build failing for Nexus 5X (bullhead)

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I'm building latest AOSP master branch for Nexus 5X (bullhead).
I'm getting below error:

```
42% 16329/38832] target thumb C: libbt-vendor_32 <= hardware/qcom/bt/msm8992/libbt-vendor/src/bt_vendor_qcom.c
**FAILED:** /**bin/bash -c "(true) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libbt-vendor_intermediates/src/) && (PWD=/proc/self/cwd  prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/3.8/bin/clang -I hardware/qcom/bt/msm8992/libbt-vendor/include -I system/bt/hci/include -I out/target/product/bullhead/obj/include/bt/hci_qcomm_init -I hardware/qcom/bt/msm8992/libbt-vendor -I out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libbt-vendor_intermediates -I out/target/product/bullhead/gen/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libbt-vendor_intermediates -I libnativehelper/include/nativehelper \$(cat out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libbt-vendor_intermediates/import_includes) -isystem system/core/include -isystem system/media/audio/include -isystem hardware/libhardware/include -isystem hardware/libhardware_legacy/include -isystem hardware/ril/include -isystem libnativehelper/include -isystem frameworks/native/include -isystem frameworks/native/opengl/include -isystem frameworks/av/include -isystem frameworks/base/include -isystem out/target/product/bullhead/obj/include -isystem device/lge/bullhead/kernel-headers -isystem hardware/qcom/msm8994/kernel-headers -isystem bionic/libc/arch-arm/include -isystem bionic/libc/include -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/common -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi/asm-arm -isystem bionic/libm/include -isystem bionic/libm/include/arm -c    -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -msoft-float -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wa,--noexecstack -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-short-enums -no-canonical-prefixes -mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=date-time -DNDEBUG -g -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fcolor-diagnostics -nostdlibinc  -target arm-linux-androideabi    -target arm-linux-androideabi -Bprebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/arm-linux-androideabi/bin    -std=gnu99     -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing   -DBT_SOC_TYPE_ROME -fPIC -D_USING_LIBCXX   -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast  -Werror=address-of-temporary -Werror=null-dereference -Werror=return-type  -MD -MF out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libbt-vendor_intermediates/src/bt_vendor_qcom.d -o out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libbt-vendor_intermediates/src/bt_vendor_qcom.o hardware/qcom/bt/msm8992/libbt-vendor/src/bt_vendor_qcom.c) && (cp out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libbt-vendor_intermediates/src/bt_vendor_qcom.d out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libbt-vendor_intermediates/src/bt_vendor_qcom.P; sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\\\\$//' -e '/^\$/ d' -e 's/\$/ :/' < out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libbt-vendor_intermediates/src/bt_vendor_qcom.d >> out/target/product/bullhead/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libbt-vendor_intermediates/src/bt_vendor_qcom.P)"
hardware/qcom/bt/msm8992/libbt-vendor/src/bt_vendor_qcom.c:811:57: warning: passing 'uint8_t [6]' to parameter of type 'char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
                                    if(rome_soc_init(fd,vnd_local_bd_addr)<0) {
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
hardware/qcom/bt/msm8992/libbt-vendor/src/bt_vendor_qcom.c:108:33: note: passing argument to parameter 'bdaddr' here
int rome_soc_init(int fd, char *bdaddr);
                                ^
hardware/qcom/bt/msm8992/libbt-vendor/src/bt_vendor_qcom.c:1003:14: warning: case value not in enumerated type 'bt_vendor_opcode_t' [-Wswitch]
        case BT_VND_OP_GET_LINESPEED:
             ^

hardware/qcom/bt/msm8992/libbt-vendor/src/bt_vendor_qcom.c:636:12: warning: enumeration values 'BT_VND_OP_SET_AUDIO_STATE', 'BT_VND_OP_A2DP_OFFLOAD_START', and 'BT_VND_OP_A2DP_OFFLOAD_STOP' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
    switch(opcode)
           ^
**hardware/qcom/bt/msm8992/libbt-vendor/src/bt_vendor_qcom.c:1034:9: error: void function 'ssr_cleanup' should not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
        return -1;**
        ^      ~~
hardware/qcom/bt/msm8992/libbt-vendor/src/bt_vendor_qcom.c:1077:5: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
    ssr_cleanup
    ^~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings and 1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:146: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
```

Please help me in resolving this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and reformat this wall of text to make it more readable?

Comment: From where you get vendor binaries for 5x ? that would help me a lot , Thank in advance

Comment: I'm just building latest AOSP for 5X. Even I couldn't get any binaries.

Comment: According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-porting/T1D3KGEOde8, there's no need to place vendor binaries manually - they are in the "vendor" partition and not touched even with ```fastboot flashall -w```.

Answer (score 0):

Disable ninja while building AOSP

```
export USE_NINJA=false
```